# Messages: Query a user's chats

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, indexing, greatest-n-per-group

For an app like [iOS Messages](https://www.apple.com/ios/messages/):

1. How should I design the server database queries & schema?

   Queries

   - Create a user.
   - Get a user's chats.
   - Get the messages between two users.
   - Add a message to a chat (creating the chat if it doesn't yet exist).

   *Note*:

   - Every chat only has two users (no group chats).
   - Every chat's `id` equals this [unique unordered pairing function](http://www.mattdipasquale.com/blog/2014/03/09/unique-unordered-pairing-function/) applied to `user_id` & `with_id`.
2. How should I query a user's chats, each with its latest message?

   Example User Interface (UI)

   [image: iOS Messages]

See my design & query on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fde14/7). It works, but how can I make it better?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651811/select-users-with-i-have-talked-and-last-message-with-them-like-whatsapp

Comment: Related: http://www.9lessons.info/2013/05/message-conversation-database-design.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459900/how-to-build-this-sql-query-select-conversation-with-last-message

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058902/sql-order-by-threads-messages

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947172/sql-querying-for-threaded-messages

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851962/mysql-query-for-thread-list-of-messages-with-specific-conditions

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317123/query-to-display-the-only-the-most-recent-message-of-each-thread

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261062/getting-the-most-recent-message-in-a-thread

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873056/facebook-style-message-inbox

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472201/mysql-group-by-order-by-issue-with-flat-messages-table-threads

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919825/sql-need-a-query-to-get-most-recent-message-in-each-thread-that-a-user-is-part

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077088/sql-show-last-messages-from-db

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027160/sql-query-for-most-recent-messages

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856416/how-to-get-the-latest-message-in-each-conversation-of-a-certain-user-in-sql

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358767/get-last-message-in-a-conversation-in-sql

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921204/creating-a-messages-list-in-sql

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144447/sql-get-last-messages-from-to-certain-user

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491967/getting-the-most-recent-date-after-using-group-by-with-mysql

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276383/postgresql-join-to-most-recent-record-between-tables

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596302/query-to-get-last-conversations-for-user-inbox

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937686/select-distinct-last-messages-by-pairs-in-postgres

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column